# Delete last added "stuff" in specific timeframe

Tags: linux, linux-mint, memory, storage

I have a major problem.

On my HP Notebook with Linux Mint I had about 220 GB of storage. I only noticed that the fan is driving crazy although I had no application open but I didn't pay any attention to it. After some hours of not working at all, I get a notification

`Only 600 MB of storage left` or something like that. After some time it went to some kilobytes.

I don't know what the hell happened. I couldn't even log in. I restarted and on the boot menu I picked `Clean storage` where I could free 250 MB so that I could at least login. If I mouse over my SSD in the Explorer, there is 0 bytes free space.

Maybe something went over the internet on my system? How can I delete all files which have been added to the system today?

Comment: Were you bitten by the [Snapd Docker catastrophic bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188908/what-does-this-docker-log-entry-mean)?

Comment: @AlexP yes, it is exactly this problem. Thank you very much.